# convert PyQt4 string styled signal to PyQt5 Signal

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4, signals-slots, qaction

I usually write a small function to create QActions. But PyQt5 doesn't support function SIGNAL() anymore. I don't know how to rewrite this function beautifully.

```
def createAction(self, text, slot=None, signal='triggered()'):
    action = QAction(text, self)
    if slot is not None:
        self.connect(action, SIGNAL(signal), slot)
    return action
```

Comment: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be over-thinking this. New-style signals are instance attributes, so you can just use [getattr](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
def createAction(self, text, slot=None, signal='triggered'):
    action = QAction(text, self)
    if slot is not None:
        getattr(action, signal).connect(slot)
    return action
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is about use a string (by name) to reference a signal.

There are three ways to connect signals under PyQt5. *see* [connecting signals by kwargs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html?highlight=pyqtsignal#connecting-signals-using-keyword-arguments) So I come out with this solution.

```
def createAction(self, text, slot=None, signal='triggered'):
    action = QAction(text, self)
    signal_dict = {'triggered':action.triggered, 'changed':action.changed,
                    'toggled':action.toggled, 'hovered':action.hovered }
    if slot is not None:
        # self.connect(action, SIGNAL(signal), slot)
        signal_dict[signal].connect(slot)
    return action
```